# Close MSSQL connection in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I'm connecting with SQL Server using Node [mssql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) in my Electron app.
I can't create REST API.

**It works fine although I have concerns:**

- it doesn't close SQL connection after query
- it makes a new DB connection for each query

**Is that ok?**

How it works:
`app.js` makes 2 queries and logs results
`sql.js` connects with DB

```
// app.js
const { getUser, getUsers } = require('./sql');

getUser(10).then((result) => {
    console.dir(result);
});

getUsers.then((result) => {
    console.dir(result);
})

// sql.js
const sql = require("mssql");

// DB credentials
const config = {
    user: 'myuser',
    password: '123',
    server: 'myserver',
    database: 'mydb',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
}

// Creates new connection pool for each query
function connectDB() {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

    return pool.connect()
        .then(pool => {
            console.log('Connected to database');

            // returns Promise
            return pool;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Database connection failed!', err));
}

// 1st query
function getUser(id) {
    const connection = connectDB();

    return connection
        .then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
                .input('PK_ID', sql.Int, parseInt(id))
                .execute('[uspGetUser]');
        })
        .then(result => {
            return result.recordset[0];
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Query failed!', err);
        });
}

// 2nd query
function getUsers() {
    const DB = connectDB();

    return DB
        .then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
                .execute('[uspGetUsers]');
        })
        .then(result => {
            return result.recordset[0];
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Query failed!', err);
        });
}

module.exports = {
    getUser,
    getUsers
}
```

Comment: I could wrap queries with `new Promise` and `resolve` results then close the connection. It works (but is it the best way?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

To close DB connection and return results, we can use **finally** statement and **asnyc/await** functions.

The **finally** statement lets you execute code, after try and catch, regardless of the result.

```
// sql.js
const sql = require("mssql");

// DB credentials
const config = {
    user: 'myuser',
    password: '123',
    server: 'myserver',
    database: 'mydb',
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
}

async function connectDB() {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

    try {
        await pool.connect();
        console.log('Connected to database');

        return pool;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Database connection failed!', err);

        return err;
    }
}

async function getAll() {
    const DB = await connectDB();

    try {
        const result = await DB.request()
            .query('select * from [your_table]');

        return result.recordset;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Error querying database', err);

        return err;
    }
    finally {
        DB.close();
    }
}

async function execute() {
    let result = await getAll();
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(result));

    return result;
}

execute();
```

Comment: How can we keep one db connection alive. Rather Than creating connection for every request

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't need to `close` a.k.a. `release` a connection back to the connection pool after every query. The library already does that for you.

The `pool.close()` method will close all the connection in the pool.  Technically, you should only do that when you're terminating your application, not after every query, since creating a new pool every time create quite an overhead on your application.

I had the same question myself, so I looked up the project's [source code](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql).

Comment: It also can create async issues between multiple different calls made around the same time.  Your global connection can be closed before you make all necessary queries if one process terminates while another is still running.

Comment: Is it necessary to call pool.close() when the application is terminating?  We're using azure functions that automatically scale down after a certain point in time and we're wondering if this could create potential memory leaks on the azure side or sql side if the connection is shut and reopened later without running pool.close()